# Finding median of masked ndarrays representing images

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy

I have 5 grayscale images in the form of 288x288 `ndarray`s.  The values in each `ndarray` are just `numpy.float32` numbers ranging from 0.0 to 255.0.  For each `ndarray`, I've created a `numpy.ma.MaskedArray` object as follows:

```
def bool_row(row):
    return [value == 183. for value in row]

mask = [bool_row(row) for row in nd_array_1]
masked_array_1 = ma.masked_array(nd_array_1, mask=mask)
```

The value `183.` represents "garbage" in the image.  All 5 images have a bit of "garbage" in them.  I want to take the median of the masked images, where taking the median for each point should ignore any masked values.  The result would be the correct image with no garbage.

When I try:

```
ma.median([masked_array_1, masked_array_2, masked_array_3, masked_array_4, masked_array_5], axis=0)
```

I get what seems to be the median except instead of ignoring masked values, it treats them as `183.`, so the result just has the superimposed garbage from all the pictures.  When I just take the median of two masked images:

```
ma.median([masked_array_1, masked_array_2], axis=0)
```

It looks like it started to do the right thing, but then placed the value of `183.` even where both masked arrays contain a `MaskedConstant`.

I could do something like the following, but I feel there's probably a way to make `ma.median` just behave as expected:

```
unmasked_array_12 = ma.median([masked_array_1, masked_array_2], axis=0)
mask = [bool_row(row) for row in unmasked_array_12]
masked_array_12 = ma.masked_array(unmasked_array_12, mask=mask)

unmasked_array_123 = ma.median([masked_array_12, masked_array_3], axis=0)
mask = [bool_row(row) for row in unmasked_array_123]
masked_array_123 = ma.masked_array(unmasked_array_123, mask=mask)

...
```

**How do I make `ma.median` work as expected without resorting to the above unpleasantness?**

Comment: Why not use, `mask = nd_array_1 == 183.`, to make your mask?

Comment: @BiRico, yeah that's a better way to make the masks, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in how `ma.median` handles a non-array argument.  It might be converting a list to a plain numpy array, without checking the types of the elements of the list.

Consider the following example with 1-D arrays:

```
In [64]: a = ma.array([1, 2, -10, 3, -10, -10], mask=[0,0,1,0,1,1])

In [65]: b = ma.array([1, 2, -10, -10, 4, -10], mask=[0,0,1,1,0,1])

In [66]: a
Out[66]: 
masked_array(data = [1 2 -- 3 -- --],
             mask = [False False  True False  True  True],
       fill_value = 999999)


In [67]: b
Out[67]: 
masked_array(data = [1 2 -- -- 4 --],
             mask = [False False  True  True False  True],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

The following are not correct--it appears to ignore the masks:

```
In [68]: ma.median([a, b])
Out[68]: -4.5

In [69]: ma.median([a, b], axis=0)
Out[69]: 
masked_array(data = [  1.    2.  -10.   -3.5  -3.  -10. ],
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

However, if I first create a new masked array using `ma.array`, `ma.median` handles it correctly:

```
In [70]: c = ma.array([a, b])

In [71]: c
Out[71]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1 2 -- 3 -- --]
 [1 2 -- -- 4 --]],
             mask =
 [[False False  True False  True  True]
 [False False  True  True False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)


In [72]: ma.median(c)
Out[72]: 2.0

In [73]: ma.median(c, axis=0)
Out[73]: 
masked_array(data = [1.0 2.0 -- 3.0 4.0 --],
             mask = [False False  True False False  True],
   fill_value = 1e+20)
```

So to fix your problem, it might be as simple as replacing this:

```
ma.median([masked_array_1, masked_array_2, masked_array_3, masked_array_4, masked_array_5], axis=0)
```

with this:

```
stacked = ma.array([masked_array_1, masked_array_2, masked_array_3, masked_array_4, masked_array_5])
ma.median(stacked, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following to get rid of all of the 183 values just while calculating the median:

```
masked_arrays=[masked_array_1, masked_array_2, masked_array_3]
no_junk_arrays=[[x for x in masked_array if x is not 183] for masked_array in masked_arrays]

ma.median(no_junk_arrays)
```

For example

```
>>> masked_array_1 = [1,183,4]
>>> masked_array_2 = [1,183,2]
>>> masked_array_3 = [2,183,2]
>>> masked_arrays=[masked_array_1,masked_array_2,masked_array_3]
>>> no_junk_arrays=[[x for x in masked_array if x is not 183] for masked_array in masked_arrays]
>>> no_junk_arrays
[[1, 4], [1, 2], [2, 2]]
```

Comment: The arrays have 183's in different places.  A slightly more realistic example would be: `ma1 = [1, 183, 2]`, `ma2 = [1, 183, 183]`, and `ma4 = [183, 4, 2]`.  The desired median would be `[1, 4, 2]`.  Note that if two arrays don't have garbage at a particular index, then they will have the same value there, since they both represent the same image, just with garbage covering different parts of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it can be done if you find the clever sequence of numpy functions to invoke.  But it can also be done naively:

```
def merge(a1, a2):
    result = []
    for x, y in zip(a1, a2):
        if x == 183:
            x = y
        result.append(x)
    return result

array_1 = [1, 183, 2]
array_2 = [1, 183, 183]
array_3 = [183, 4, 2]

print merge(merge(array_1, array_2), array_3)
```

If the result runs really too slowly, you can try the same code on PyPy instead of CPython.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are after is fetching the non-nan value for every pixel, you could do someting along the lines of:

```
stacked_imgs = np.dstack((img1, img2, img3))
mask = stacked_imgs == 183
# Find the first False, i.e. non-183 entry, along stack axis
index = np.argmin(mask, axis=-1)
correct_image = stacked_image[..., index]
```

If all non-183 entries for a given pixel are always the same, this will give you the result you are after.